# Can you link one workflow over two different sharepoint 2007 sites

Tags: sharepoint, workflow, task

We have two different SharePoint 2007 sites for our company and want to create a workflow that will connect the two. Basically, we would like to take a workflow along with its task list and have it on both sites. When the workflow is updated on one site, it should automatically update the other site as well. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

A workflow is assigned to a list, CT, or Site so most likely you will not have one workflow that will accomplish what you are wanting.

Without knowing what you are actually doing the best I can do is take a guess.

Your workflow could modify other items on another site so that when you complete a task on site 1 the workflow updates site 2.  If you complete a task on site 2 it would update the task on site 1.  (This is easiest if the sites are in the same farm but usually the need for what you want to do is because you have multiple farms)

For this your workflow would need an association field that you would enter the url of the other site.

If you could provide more information about why you need 2 sites you may get some better answers.